# Adobe Illustrator (2017 Release) Crashes on Launch | Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, crash, adobe-illustrator

This problem has been occurring since I got my new laptop, **Windows 10 64x**, and installed my normal Adobe products I use. **All of the other Adobe apps, like Premiere and After Effects work completely fine**. But when I open Illustrator, it **gets past the splash screen** and opens the normal app window with the grey background. It sits there for a second then crashes with **no dialogue box**, nor does it ask about doing diagnostics on the next start. Additionally, **no log is given**, unless it's in a folder somewhere, I don't know. 
As I've read about Wacom drivers, I've **never had Wacom drivers** on my computer. The only pen device I have is a **Huion tablet** with it's latest drivers.

I've tried...

- Reinstalling it (Uninstall and Install from Adobe CC)
- Deleting preferences from %AppData%/Roaming/Adobe/Adobe Illustrator 21 Settings/
- Downloading Adobe's supposed missing file to put in /Adobe Illustrator 21 Settings/
- the shortcut Alt+Ctrl+Shift during startup, has no effect.
- Moving around plug-ins to which **Illustrator starts to the Welcome page** but then forces you to restart it, and continues crashing. (This is a *likely* cause, but I don't know how to fix it)
- Running diagnostics (when it let me), to which it reported nothing.

Also, **I don't have any font manager I know of**. I've never touched anything with fonts, other than installing **Roboto** to the Windows font folder. I really know nothing about font managers, so if it is the case please tell me without assuming any prior knowledge.

Is it possible to install a older version? The CC Manager doesn't allow it anymore, but it would make things a lot easier.

**EDIT:**
I tried opening a Illustrator save file from a while ago instead of opening it directly. It opens and shows the illustration that I made but doesn't finish populating all of the buttons and tool panels before it crashes.

Comment: Have you tried Adobe support?

Comment: yes, in the past. didn't help, just told me to try what I've already did.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: You should continue to work with Adobe on this issue.